# MVC Can't Access WCF Data Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf-data-services

I've added a WCF Data Service (v5.6) called test.svc to the root of my MVC app but I can't seem to get my routing figured out so that I can access it. Below are the results I get back in the browser when I go to http:/test.svc along with my route code and test.svc file.

route table entry (first route rule I add):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");


[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class test : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
```

Error shown in browser:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Expression of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' cannot be used for
>   return type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext''. See server logs for
>   more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type
>   delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body,
>   ParameterExpression[] parameters) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.CreateDbContextAccessor(Type
>   type) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.GetDbContextAccessor(Type
>   type) at
>   System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.IsDbContextType(Type
>   type) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider&
>   metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider&
>   queryProviderInstance, Object& dataSourceInstance, Boolean&
>   isInternallyCreatedProvider) at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.EnsureProviderAndConfigForRequest()
>   at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at
>   System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream
>   messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like WCF DS and EF 6 are incompatible and there's no timeframe for when, or if, they might fix things.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4aa92957-22de-4445-aecd-2871982afe28/eta-on-entity-framework-version-6-provider?prof=required